# Should I update from 18:04 LTS Ubuntu Server to 20.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, server, upgrade, raid

For some time now my server running headless Ubuntu server, has been telling me to upgrade Ubuntu to 20.04.3 LTS, but I have no means of backing up 1.8TB of data stored on a 12TB (12x8) Raid 5 setup, so, if the current 18.04 LTS is running out soon, how safe (without backups) is it to use 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade and have a running system without screw-ups?  Or should I just keep using 18.04 being that it has been running now for a little under a year without problems?

Comment: Breakup your data!

Comment: Edited tag: Changed 14.04 to 18.04

Comment: RAID5 offers great data protection, but it's not as great as a real backup that you know how to restore from. Hardware fails, server rooms flood, malware strikes, admins make catastrophic typos. Murphy's Law applies: If you make regular backups, your server will work perfectly for a decade. The week you skip a backup, everything catches fire.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server 18.04 has five years of mainline support, so you can continue to use it and receive updates without interruption until April of 2023. At that time, if you want to keep using 18.04, it is recommended that you join the [Extended Security Maintenance](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm) program to continue receiving security updates.